# How to populate array of objects with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following schemas in mongoose:

```
var documentsSchema = new Schema({
"document" : {
    "_project"          : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref  : 'Projects'
    },
    "_addedBy"          : {
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref  : 'Users'
    },
    "_associateUsers"   : [{
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref  : 'Users'
    }],
    "_codes"            : [{
        type : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref  : 'Codes'
    }],
    "paragraphTitle"    : String,
    "paragraphText"     : String,

    "memos"             : [
    {
        "_addedBy"      : {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'Users'
        },
        "memoData"      : String
    }
]}});
```

and the Codes:

```
var codesSchema = new Schema({
"code" : {

    "_addedBy"      : {
        type    : Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref     : 'Users'
    },
    "codeText"      : String,
    "codeWeight"    : Number
}});
```

I need to populate _codes.codeText (or codes fields) of the all elements of the array, but looks like I am not doing it properly.

```
Documents.find({
            "document._project": element._id
            }).
            populate('document._codes.code','codeText'). 
            exec(function (err, result) { .... }
```

this and various tries with populate arguments are either not populating the fields or not returning any data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the schema, but not the model. The `_codes` has a ref to the model `Codes` but it doesn't exists. When you call `.populate` with the first two params it assumes that the model is `Codes` (taked from reference)

To fix this, toy need to add:

```
mongoose.model('Codes', codesSchema);
mongoose.model('Documents', documentsSchema);
```

Maybe you need to do the same with `Users`

See the complete documentation for `populate` [**here**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate)

**P.S.** A recommendation: If you are defining an schema for `codes` or whatever you don't need to define again the name of the object as part of the same schema, look:

From this

```
//your style
var catsSchema = new Schema({
    "cat" : {
        "attr1" : {type: ...},
        "attr2" : {type: ...}
    }
});
```

to this

```
//obviously attr1 and attr2 are part of cat object/document
var catsSchema = new Schema({
    "attr1" : {type: ...},
    "attr2" : {type: ...}
});
```

Comment: I have those, but didn't paste them in the question: 
    var Codes = mongoose.model('Codes', codesSchema, 'codes');
regarding the PS, I am doing it for the template engine, where this is necessary, but I didn't realized at the beginning that I might add that to the data, passed for rendering, not the document itself.

Comment: and also this is working well: 
Project.find({
        "project._addedBy": query
    }).populate('project._addedBy', 'name.first name.last').
    lean(true).exec(findDocs);

Comment: can you try this? : Documents.find({...}).populate('document._codes').exec({...})

Comment: and this: Documents.find({...}).populate('document._codes.code', 'code.codeText').exec({...})

Comment: Actually, now I'm getting an empty array :/. The problem is with the arrays

Comment: it might be also with the too much nesting I will try to get out the unnecessary nesting one level..

Comment: In some hours I will have a free time to view again this. Wich version of mongoose you are using?

Comment: it is mongoose 3.8.14

Comment: 3.8.15 has same problem

Comment: I edited the schemas to up one level as suggested in the PS and that was ok.

Comment: oh! very well.. I think is not a complete solution, but it works